# Git: why we have to run 'git merge' twice?

Tags: git, merge

Often, in a simple branch merge, when I first run `git merge <branch_name>`, no actual merging (or fast-forwarding) is happening: Git reports something like this:

```
$ git merge <branch_name>  
Updating ccd6d17..bd32447

$
```

Then when I run the same `git merge <branch_name>` command for the second time, it is working fine:

```
$ git merge <branch_name>  
Updating ccd6d17..bd32447

$ git merge <branch_name>
Updating ccd6d17..bd32447
Fast-forward
 <file1>                                    |   1 -
 <file2>                                    |   8 +-
 ....
 14 files changed, 379 insertions(+), 83 deletions(-)

$
```

I can't find any explanation for this behavior. Is this the expected behavior (at least in some cases)?

Comment: Does the issue persists when run in a bash (type "bash" to enter the Git bash)

Comment: @VonC I do run this in Git Bash - through ConEmu though

Comment: Ok, the `>` confused me: in a bash you would see `$`

Comment: oh, sorry, i just typed this :)

Comment: So reverse question: would the issue persists in a regular CMD session? (on ConEmu or in a simple CMD Window)

Comment: Yes - just tried this and saw the same thing... I have an alias `alias m="git merge"`, but both alias and full name result in above behavior. I guess my main question is that is this ever-expected Git behavior, or it looks more like a bug somwhere?

Comment: More like a bug to me. Can you reproduce that on another computer, with a simple Git for Windows installation?

Comment: Can you do a run with verbose on (-v)? Maybe something is reported and could help you identify the issue.

Comment: Can you provide reflog please? Just run `git reflog -n10`. Thanks.